# Init container in openshift

Tags: kubernetes, containers, openshift, kubernetes-pod, openshift-3

I am new to openshift, I have gone through Openshift website for more details but wanted to know if anyone has deployed init container.
I want to use that to take dump from database and restore it to new version of it with the help of init container
We are using postgres database

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, could you please elaborate -  what is the problem? What have you tried, and how is it not working? The [Openshift documentation](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.1/nodes/containers/nodes-containers-init.html) has plenty of details about how to use initContainers, what do you need clarification about?

Comment: @lxop
I have postgres9 container now I want to upgrade it to postgress 10, but I want to use same deployment config 
My concept was before deploying postgres10 I want to dump postgres9 data to persistent volume then import that in postgres 9  so how I can use initcontainer to get this work , I have tried  with shell script but that i am using after taking manual dump to automate this wanted to know how we can use init containers
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to use that to take dump from database and restore it to new version of it with the help of init container

I would say you should rather use the operator instead of initContainer. Take a look at below [Init Containers Design Considerations](https://www.magalix.com/blog/kubernetes-patterns-the-init-container-pattern)

There are some considerations that you should take into account when you create initcontainers:

- They always get executed before other containers in the Pod. So, they
  shouldn’t contain complex logic that takes a long time to complete.
  Startup scripts are typically small and concise. If you find that
  you’re adding too much logic to init containers, you should consider
  moving part of it to the application container itself.
- Init containers are started and executed in sequence. An init
  container is not invoked unless its predecessor is completed
  successfully. Hence, if the startup task is very long, you may
  consider breaking it into a number of steps, each handled by an init
  container so that you know which steps fail.
- If any of the init containers fail, the whole Pod is restarted
  (unless you set restartPolicy to Never). Restarting the Pod means
  re-executing all the containers again including any init containers.
  So, you may need to ensure that the startup logic tolerates being
  executed multiple times without causing duplication. For example, if
  a DB migration is already done, executing the migration command again
  should just be ignored.
- An init container is a good candidate for delaying the application
  initialization until one or more dependencies are available. For
  example, if your application depends on an API that imposes an API
  request-rate limit, you may need to wait for a certain time period to
  be able to receive responses from that API. Implementing this logic
  in the application container may be complex; as it needs to be
  combined with health and readiness probes. A much simpler way would
  be creating an init container that waits until the API is ready
  before it exits successfully. The application container would start
  only after the init container has done its job successfully.
- Init containers cannot use health and readiness probes as application
  containers do. The reason is that they are meant to start and exit
  successfully, much like how Jobs and CronJobs behave.
- All containers on the same Pod share the same Volumes and network.
  You can make use of this feature to share data between the
  application and its init containers.

---

The only thing I found about using it for dumping data is this [example](https://www.magalix.com/blog/kubernetes-patterns-the-init-container-pattern) about doing that with mysql, maybe it can guide you how to do it with postgresql.

> In this scenario, we are serving a MySQL database. This database is used for testing an application. It doesn’t have to contain real data, but it must be seeded with enough data so that we can test the application's query speed. We use an init container to handle downloading the SQL dump file and restore it to the database, which is hosted in another container. This scenario can be illustrated as below:

[image]

> The definition file may look like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: mydb
  labels:
    app: db
spec:
  initContainers:
    - name: fetch
      image: mwendler/wget
      command: ["wget","--no-check-certificate","https://sample-videos.com/sql/Sample-SQL-File-1000rows.sql","-O","/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/dump.sql"]
      volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
          name: dump
  containers:
    - name: mysql
      image: mysql
      env:
        - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
          value: "example"
      volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
          name: dump
  volumes:
    - emptyDir: {}
      name: dump
```

> The above definition creates a Pod that hosts two containers: the init container and the application one. Let’s have a look at the interesting aspects of this definition:
>
> The init container is responsible for downloading the SQL file that contains the database dump. We use the mwendler/wget image because we only need the wget command.
> The destination directory for the downloaded SQL is the directory used by the MySQL image to execute SQL files (/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d). This behavior is built into the MySQL image that we use in the application container.
> The init container mounts /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d to an emptyDir volume. Because both containers are hosted on the same Pod, they share the same volume. So, the database container has access to the SQL file placed on the emptyDir volume.

---

Additionally for best practices I would suggest to take a look at kubernetes operators, as far as I know that's the best practice way to menage databases in kubernetes.

If you're not familiar with operators I would suggest to start with kubernetes [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/extend-kubernetes/operator/#operators-in-kubernetes) and this short [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ha3LjlD6g7g) on youtube.

Operators are methods of packaging Kubernetes that enable you to more easily manage and monitor stateful applications. There are many operators already available, such as the

- [Crunchy Data PostgreSQL Operator](https://github.com/CrunchyData/postgres-operator)
- [Postgres Operator](https://github.com/zalando/postgres-operator)

which automates and simplifies deploying and managing open source PostgreSQL clusters on Kubernetes by providing the essential features you need to keep your PostgreSQL clusters up and running.